# Sqlite database not copied from asset folder Android

Tags: android, sqlite, copy, assets

I am trying to copy a database named "adinpect" from the asset folder to the application databases folder, but it is not working...

Code (in main activity onCreate(), just for testing):

```
 try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases";
        File f = new File(destPath);

        if (!f.exists()) {

            f.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
            //---copy the db from the assets folder into the databases folder---
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("adinspect"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/adinspect"));
        }

    } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


 public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

        //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

}//end copyDB
```

The "databases" folder is created but there in nothing in it, trying to access it by DDMS.

I do not get any errors.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper`, which has all of this debugged in a reusable component: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @CommonsWare: using SQLiteAssetHelper, my app crashes when I try to copy a database with the table "android_metadata" in it. Removing that table make it work again. I am targeting Android 4+ only, I guess the specs changed and that table is not required any more but auto-generated?

Comment: "Crashes" is a useless description of your symptoms. Here is a sample project that does not crash, at least the last time I ran it: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks. I solved the problem using the library you suggested ;)

Comment: Crashes is not "useless" just not descriptive enough for you CommonsWare.  It's like someone saying they are sick, we would like more info but I understand that they are not well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code wlll help you to copy DB from assets folder.
You can check first if DB exists or not.

```
try{
    // CHECK IS EXISTS OR NOT
    SQLiteDatabase dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/"+getPackageName+"/databases/dbname.sqlite",null, 0);
    dbe.close();
}
catch(Exception e)}
{
    // COPY IF NOT EXISTS
    AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/"+getPackageName+"/databases/dbname.sqlite");
    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    int r;
    InputStream is = am.open("dbname.sqlite");
    while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
         os.write(b, 0, r);
   }
   is.close();
   os.close();
}
```

Comment: Not Working! could not open file