# Error while copying sqlite database from asset folder of android project to the prefered location

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting following error when i am trying to copy database from asset folder .

```
Error:  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3470), pid=6696, tid=4792
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# hs_err_pid6696.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

link of the code : 
[Sqlite database not copied from asset folder Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713640/sqlite-database-not-copied-from-asset-folder-android)

Edit:

```
AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    OutputStream os = new    FileOutputStream("/data/data/"+getPackageName+"/databases/dbname.sqlite");
    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    int r;
    InputStream is = am.open("dbname.sqlite");
    while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
         os.write(b, 0, r);
   }
   is.close();
   os.close();
}
```

I am trying to run this code..
This code copies the database from asset folder in android.
when i run this code..it shows the above error

Comment: This error is from a Sun JVM, not Android. You may wish to edit your question to explain, *precisely*, where you are getting this error and what you are doing to cause the error.

Comment: I have solved the issue..
the problem was that i was running the android app as java application and not as android application so it caused this JVM issue..
i have set the run configuration in eclipse accordingly..

Comment: add an answer describing your solution/cause and mark it as the right answer, please @Prannoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error was caused as the app was running as a normal java application and not an android application.

Just change the run configuration of the project in eclipse to android application to solve the above problem. thanks